# Flask Python Authentication error: identity = getattr(identity, 'id') or identity['id']

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I am trying a simple authentication logic using Flask and flask_jwt, it used to work normally but all of a sudden I started getting this exception:
`identity = getattr(identity, 'id') or identity['id']`

here is my user model:

```
class UserModel:
    def __init__(self, id, username, password):
        self._id = id
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    @classmethod
    def find_by_username(cls, username):
        db = sqlite3.connect(path)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?'
        result = cursor.execute(query, (username,))
        row = result.fetchone()
        if row:
            user = cls(*row)
        else:
            user = None
        db.close()
        return user

    @classmethod
    def find_by_id(cls, _id):
        db = sqlite3.connect(path)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?'
        result = cursor.execute(query, (_id,))
        row = result.fetchone()
        if row:
            user = cls(*row)
        else:
            user = None
        db.close()
        return user
```

here is my security module:

```
def authenticate(username, password):
    print("authenticate was called.")
    user = UserModel.find_by_username(username)
    print(user)
    if user and safe_str_cmp(user.password, password):
        return user

def identity(payload):
    user = payload['identity']
    return UserModel.find_by_id(user)
```

I can't figure out what is causing this exception, I am aware that there are more sophisticated ways to go about this, but I am building on my app from a simple rudimentary one to a more in line with current practices one, here is the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EM\PycharmProjects\Learn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  ...
  File "C:\Users\EM\PycharmProjects\Learn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt\__init__.py", line 125, in _default_auth_request_handler
    access_token = _jwt.jwt_encode_callback(identity)
  File "C:\Users\EM\PycharmProjects\Learn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt\__init__.py", line 62, in _default_jwt_encode_handler
    payload = _jwt.jwt_payload_callback(identity)
  File "C:\Users\EM\PycharmProjects\Learn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt\__init__.py", line 53, in _default_jwt_payload_handler
    identity = getattr(identity, 'id') or identity['id']
AttributeError: 'UserModel' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the docs, (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/) Flask jtf requires your `User` class to have an `id` attribute, not an `_id` attribute

[image]

Comment: @ClsForCookies but when I use `id` instead of `_id` I get this message: `Shadows built-in name 'id'`

Comment: This is a good warning, and it seems the developer of flask jwt ignored it. Either ignore the warning, or don't use this module as it is. Shadowing built ins is not the end of the world, but it can cause some really nasty bugs

Comment: @ClsForCookies thank you very much for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: Np. I actually learned something new because of u. Thanks